Calculating Operator Norm for : $M : l^p \to l^r$
I was solving the following problem :

Let $M=(k_{i,j})$ be an infinite matrix with scalar entries and $$\alpha _{p,r}=
\begin{matrix}
    sup_{j=1,2,...}(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|k_{i,j}|^r)^{1/r} & if  & p=1,1\le r\ <\infty \\
    sup_{i=1,2,...}(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|k_{i,j}|^q)^{1/q} & if  & 1<p \le \infty, \frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1, r=\infty \\
    sup_{i,j=1,2,...} \vert k_{i,j} \vert & if & p=1,r=\infty \\
\end{matrix}$$If $\alpha _{p,r}<\infty $, then $M$ defines a continuous linear map from $l^p$ to $l^r$ and its operator norm equals $\alpha_{p,r}$.

In this exercise, I am showing my calculations for the first case $(1\le r<\infty,p=1)$ :
$$\Vert Mx \Vert _r=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|Mx(i)|^r\right)^{1/r}=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}k_{i,j}x(j)|^r\right)^{1/r}\le \left(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|k_{i,j}x(j)|^r\right)^{1/r} \le \left(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|k_{i,j}|^r|x(j)|^r\right)^{1/r} \le \alpha_{1,r}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|x(j)|^r\right)^{1/r}=\alpha_ {1,r}\Vert x \Vert_r $$ Here, $\alpha_{1,r}<\infty $, so $M$ defines a continuous map from $l^1$ to $l^r$.
But, my genuine hurdle in this exercise is showing the operator norm equals $\alpha_{1,r}$. I am unable to find an $x\in X$ s.t. $\Vert x \Vert_{1}=1$ and also $\Vert Mx \Vert_{r}=\alpha_{1,r}$, I mean the process I am following to calculate this norm. Please help me. Thank you beforehand!!!
Is there any general trick to guess the $x$ for which the norm will be attained?

Concerning $p=1,$ assume $M:\ell^1\to X,$ where $X$ is a normed space. Let $e_j$ denote the elements of the standard basis in $\ell^1.$ Clearly $\|M\|\ge \|Me_j\|_X,$ hence $$\|M\|\ge \sup_j\|Me_j\|$$ Assume $\sup_j\|Me_j\|_X<\infty.$ Then for $x\in \ell^1$ we have $$\|Mx\|_X=\left\|\sum_jx_jMe_j\right \|_X\\ \le \sum_j|x_j|\,\|Me_j\|_X \le \sup_j\|Me_j\|_X\,\|x\|_1$$ Formally the estimates should be performed for $x$ with finitely many nonzero entries. Thus $$\|M\|\le \sup_j\|Me_j\|_X$$ Summarizing we got $$\|M\|= \sup_j\|Me_j\|_X$$ Applying the above to $X=\ell^r$ with $1\le r<\infty $ gives $$\|M\|=\sup_j\left (\sum_i|k_{ij}|^r\right )^{1/r}$$
For $r=\infty$ we get $$\|M\|=\sup_j\sup_i|k_{ij}|$$ The case $p>1$ and $r=\infty$ can be dealt by duality: $(\ell^p)^*= \ell^q$ and $(\ell^1)^* =\ell^\infty.$
Namely consider the operator $M_0:\ell^1\to \ell^q$ corresponding to the matrix $(\overline{k_{ji}}).$
According to the above we get for $1<p\le \infty$ $$\|M_0\|=\sup_i\left (\sum_j|k_{ji}|^q\right )^{1/q}$$ We have $M_0^*=M.$ Since $\|M_0\|=\|M\|$ we get the desired formula.

Thank you so much, your answer is helpful. It gives me a new insight to rethink the problems of calculating operator norms.
